# How can I setup IHttpClientAdapter.GetAsync to return a HttpResponseMessage with particular value for IsSuccessStatusCode?

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I have a class that has a dependency on the `IHttpClientAdapter`, which I am using to call a RESTful API.

I have a test for the method that uses the dependency, so I am mocking the `IHttpClientAdapter` using `Moq`. The test should check that when the `GetAsync` method returns **any** unsuccessful response, something happens.

One thing that I could do is create a new `HttpResponseMessage` like so:

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage
{
    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
};
```

Then setup the mocked dependency to return that like so:

```
_httpClientAdapterMock.Setup(x => x.GetAsync(new Uri("http://someuri"))).ReturnsAsync(response);
```

`IsSuccessfulStatusCode` in this case would evaluate to false, so the test passes as one would expect.

However, this test is not as robust as I'd like it to be, as it only checks one particular response code. What I would really like to do is set the `IsSuccessfulStatusCode` to false instead. So something like this:

```cs
var response = new HttpResponseMessage
{
    IsSuccessStatusCode = false // cannot do this, as IsSuccessStatusCode is readonly
};
```

I have tried extending the `HttpResponseMessage` (named `FakeHttpResponseMessage`), creating an instance of that class and setting the `IsSuccessStatusCode` property to true, and then setup the mock to return that instead, but the `IsSuccessStatusCode` property evaluates to `true` when running the test, so it didn't have the desired effect.

How can this be achieved, without having to test each and every possible unsuccessful `HttpStatusCode`?

Comment: can't we mock HttpResponseMessage for IsSuccessStatusCode to return false and return this mock object in the GetAsync call of the httpClientAdapterMock Setup?

Comment: Not answering, since I don't know the moq syntax, but yes, the mock adapter should be set up to return a mock response.

Answer (score -2):

It's probably going to be something like Set the response.status = 200 because 200 is the response code for success.

Comment: Please be more  precise and descriptive in your answer, currently it is not very helpful.